# How to read mail using msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, msbuildcommunitytasks, msbuild-propertygroup

Is there any way to read mail contents using msbuild? Any custom tasks or community tasks available to achieve this?

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want to do this?

Comment: I want to pass properties to script through mail

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want to pass properties through email? sorry but I'm curious :)

Comment: we are having a target where based on property name different action will be done. So without giving permission to build machine ,we can ask them send mail to particular mail id. based on the property name they passed in mail , different action will be taken.

Comment: What can I say but [Zawinski's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski), "Every program attempts to expand until it can read mail. Those programs which cannot so expand are replaced by ones which can".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom task.

See these links for example code:
[Read MS Exchange email in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c-sharp)
[C# MAPI to read exchange server inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065017/c-sharp-mapi-to-read-exchange-server-inbox)
[Read Gmail Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461946/read-gmail-inbox)